# Using statements for common object types

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, xamarin

In Xamarin, I am trying this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html

Here is the code:

```
List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
    planet.Put(key, name);

    return planet;
}
```

May I please have some help with the correct using statements for the following types:

- Map
- ArrayList
- HashMap

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Map and ArrayMap are in java.util.  ArrayList is in System.Collections.